# Read Docx files via python

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Does anyone know a python library to read docx files?

I have a word document that I am trying to read data from.

Comment: I would use `python-docx`

Comment: Isn't it meant for writing? Not for reading

Comment: What information do you want to get out of the docx file? Just text? Images? Metadata?

Comment: It's just text, but in the same format as the document

Comment: another way to go, is to convert the `.docx` to `.odt` using libreoffice commandline and then inspect the `.odt` file. AFAIK odt python tools are better than docx.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of packages that let you do this.
Check

1. [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
2. [docx2txt](https://pypi.org/project/docx2txt/) (note that it does not seem to work with `.doc`). As per [this](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt), it seems to get more info than python-docx.
   From original documentation:

```
import docx2txt

# extract text
text = docx2txt.process("file.docx")

# extract text and write images in /tmp/img_dir
text = docx2txt.process("file.docx", "/tmp/img_dir")
```

3. [textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (which works via [docx2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt)).
4. Since `.docx` files are simply `.zip` files with a changed extension, [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-data-from-ms-word-documents-using-python-ed3fbb48c122) shows how to access the contents.
   This is a significant difference with `.doc` files, and the reason why some (or all) of the above do not work with `.doc`s.
   In this case, you would likely have to convert `doc` -> `docx` first. `antiword` is an option.

Answer (score 4):

python-docx can read as well as write.

```
doc = docx.Document('myfile.docx')
allText = []
for docpara in doc.paragraphs:
    allText.append(docpara.text)
```

Now all paragraphs will be in the list allText.

Thanks to [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com) by Al Sweigart for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

See this library that allows for reading docx files https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You should use the python-docx library available on PyPi. Then you can use the following

```
doc = docx.Document('myfile.docx')
allText = []
for docpara in doc.paragraphs:
    allText.append(docpara.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick [search of PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=docx&submit=search) turns up the [docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx/0.2.4) package.

Comment: I know about the docx package, it is meant for writing not reading :/

Comment: ["The docx module creates, reads and writes Microsoft Office Word 2007 docx files."](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx/0.2.4)

Answer (score 1):

```
import docx

def main():
    try:
        doc = docx.Document('test.docx')  # Creating word reader object.
        data = ""
        fullText = []
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            fullText.append(para.text)
            data = '\n'.join(fullText)

        print(data)

    except IOError:
        print('There was an error opening the file!')
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and dont forget to install **python-docx** using (pip install python-docx)